# How to reverse an array using foreach without using the Reverse() method

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, reverse

This is an extra credit assignment for my C# class.  Its easy to reverse the array using the method but im extrodinarily confused on how to do it without using it.  Any hints or help  would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace Reverse4Loop 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        foreach (int value in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();


        Array.Reverse(array);
        foreach (int value in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There must be a reason for that extra credit.

Comment: There's a different form of for loop, one that uses index. Reversing the index counter (3 to 0 instead of 0 to 3) should do the job.

Comment: Did the assignment explicitly say use the `foreach` or have you jumped to that particular loop on your own?

Comment: Think about array indices and swapping values around.

Comment: you need to write them in reverse order, or actually create a new array with them in reverse order? maybe reverse in the same array?

Comment: reverse in-place with `foreach` seem to be an entertaining task. Or you actually have less restrictive requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using `foreach` and a temporal `List<int>`:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> aux = new List<int>();
foreach (int i in array)
    aux.Insert(0, i);
int[] reversed = aux.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra credit is offered to help motivate you to learn. Please try to learn from this answer, and don't just copy/paste it.

One of the powers of LINQ is its ability to order: ascending and descending. If ascending means to go upward (i.e., forward), then descending can be said to be the reverse.

Using LINQ, this is how you would write out the array in ascending order:

```
foreach (var value in array.OrderBy(a => a))
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Now, before you hover over the answer below to find out how to do it in reverse, use intellisense in Visual Studio, or google *LINQ descending order* and determine what method you would replace `OrderBy` with, to write out the array in descending order:

**Answer**

> foreach(var value in array.OrderByDescending(a => a))
>  Console.WriteLine(value);

*Hover over the above box to reveal the solution*

Comment: Note that your answer does not show reverse at all - it shows sorting in different order which some would not consider reverse.

Comment: Changing the ascending order of a list of numbers that ascend from 1-4, to a descending order, effectively reverses said list.

Answer (score -1):

Check if this works for you :) This is the typical way to do it. But are the expecting something else on giving extra credits?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int length = array.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[length - 1 - i];
        array[length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
    foreach (int value in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, college sure would be easy if I had someone to do all of the extra-credit assignments for me for free.

Comment: I shall share my bank details... :) send them all if it's are of this type :P. These are pretty easy if you understand the way we use the loops, indices and simple logic you can make it happen, there you're. You can solve the same problem in different ways. like e.g. You can use a while loop to do this, you can iterate the whole length and break in the loops body... keep in mind that code must simple, elegant and efficient.

Comment: -1: I don't see "reverse array using foreach" in the suggested code. You could as well just add comment `// foreach word used` and be done with it... also it could be goal of the assignment :)

Comment: I don't find in your code that you should do it with foreach only. If this is a typical assignment and stuck with foreach I have nothing to say. For each is used to iterate through collection or array not change the contents.

See documentation below
The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each element in an array or an object collection. The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the desired information, but `should not be used to change the contents of the collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.`

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace Reverse4Loop 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        foreach (int value in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        int arrayLength = array.Length;

        int[] array2 = new int[arrayLength];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array2[arrayLength - (i + 1)] = array[i];
        }

        Array.Copy(array2, array, arrayLength);

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you